# What is the fastest way to replace all zeros in a matrix?

Tags: matrix

In the following matrix `m` every 0 should be replaced with a 1:

```
m = {{0,1,2},{5,0,3},{8,0,0}}
```

Desired result:

```
m' = {{1,1,2},{5,1,3},{8,1,1}}
```

What is the fastest way to do this for a matrix with 200-1000 elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
m + 1 - Unitize[m]
```

might be faster because it preserves packed arrays, but we'd need a real test.

Comment: You likely need `Unitize` in place of `UnitStep`.

Comment: This is wrong if the matrix contains negative integers. Like @LeonidShifrin said, `Unitize` is the correct function here.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin and RunnyKine - thanks. Indeed, I was taking the example quite literally -- `Unitize` is more general and does handle negative numbers.

Comment: It's definitely fast so +1.

Comment: For me this is the fastest

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun: the following hack is even slightly faster than the solution using `Unitize` and vectorization, on really large matrices:

```
replaceZeros[m_?MatrixQ] := 
   Normal[
      SparseArray[m] /. HoldPattern[SparseArray[s___]] :>
          Module[{parts = {s}},
            parts[[3]] = 1;
            SparseArray @@ parts
          ]
   ];
```

but, in this forms at least, it explicitly uses the fact that elements being replaced are zeros. This is just for fun, in any case.

Comment: `Unitize` is twice as fast on my PC for `10^7` element matrix.

Comment: @RunnyKine I used also 10^7 elements, and on my machine (Mac OS X 10.7.5 64 bit), `Unitize` is about 10-20 % slower. Which version of Mathematica you used?

Comment: Perhaps you 2 used different proportion of zeros? If lots of zeros probably Leonid's wins, and viceversa

Comment: I'm using V9.0.1 Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: @Rojo Yes, I already noticed that too. But even if the zeros are very scarce, on my machine my code then is just the same speed as the one with `Unitize`.

Comment: @RunnyKine Well, I am using a different M version - this could be the reason for the difference, apart from a different platform.

Comment: I suppose, since I've tried different generation of the matrix (even limiting the `Random` generator to only `0` and `1`) and every time, `Unitize` is at least twice as fast on my machine.

Comment: If the element to be replaced were a common element, then I don't see why it would kill the speed advantage. Just change the common element using `SparseArray[m, Automatic, toBeReplaced]`, instead.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, you are right, and I was wrong. Still, this is a hack, because it uses the implementation details of `SparseArray` to achieve its goals. But I like it.

Comment: Dangit, I wanted to post this. +1 :-)

Comment: Hack, yes. Useful, yes. +1

Answer (score 4):

```
m = {{0, 1, 2}, {5, 0, 3}, {8, 0, 0}} /. 0 -> 1
{{1, 1, 2}, {5, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1}}
```

It's certainly the fastest to write down.

Comment: Why `//.` instead of `/.`?

Comment: @Timothy Wofford -- habit, I guess. `/.` is shorter. Rojo -- habit again. I"m always nervous when a white space means something though, as in: `/. 0->1` is OK but `/.0->1` is not.

Comment: For me /. is 25% faster than //.

Answer (score 3):

```
Replace[m, 0 -> 1, Infinity]
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {5, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1}}

Answer (score 0):

```
{{0, 1, 2}, {5, 0, 3}, {8, 0, 0}} //. {a___, 0, b___} -> {a, 1, b}
```

> {{1, 1, 2}, {5, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1}}

For,

```
RandomInteger[0, {100000, 3}] //. {a___, 0, b___} -> {a, 1, b};
```

> 2.62 Sec

Comment: Try with `RandomInteger[{0, 5}, {10^7, 3}]`

Comment: @RunnyKine : ya you seem to be right, upto 10^6 its taking 16 sec, after that sort of bottleneck.