# Strange behaviour of Internal`InheritedBlock

Tags: functions, scoping, undocumented

I was going to post an answer for [fast way to replace all zeros in the matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34675/5478). I was even quite happy because timings were the same order of magnitude as others.

The idea was to overwrite `Identity`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Identity}, Unprotect[Identity]; Identity[0] = 1; 

   Map[Identity, {{2, 0}, {Pi, 9}}, {2}]]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1}, {Pi, 9}}
> ```

But I've checked that for bigger matrices the result is not even close to the expected one:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Identity}, Unprotect[Identity]; Identity[0] = 1; 

   m = RandomInteger[1, {100, 2}]; 
   Map[Identity, m, {2}] ~ Shallow ~ {5, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, <<98>>}
> ```

---

It seem it breaks at **size** of the array of about $90$ positions:

```
 test = Internal`InheritedBlock[{Identity}, Unprotect[Identity]; Identity[0] = 1;

         Apply[
          Boole[Map[Identity, RandomInteger[1, {##}], {2}] == ConstantArray[1, {##}]
               ]&,                     
          Array[List, {35, 35}],
          {2}]];

Show[MatrixPlot[test, DataReversed -> True, Mesh -> All],
     ContourPlot[x y == 90, {x, 1, 35}, {y, 1, 35}]
     , BaseStyle -> {Thickness@.01, 18}]
```

[image]

---

I hope I haven't missed anything obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps that's when Map starts compiling

Comment: I fiddled with `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength"]` and the plot changed, but now even after restarting the kernel I can't reproduce the original plot. Strange indeed :)

Comment: @ssch I must admit I have not done much compiling in MMA, so could you explain, even if it is so, why `Map` does not care about overwritten definition?

Comment: I can only speculate, I guess that the compiler sees `Identity` and assumes it knows how that behaves, not looking for changed definition.

Comment: @ssch I see, I think I saw here similar question about `Sin` behaviour is some circumstances, but I can recall it.

Comment: `Map` auto-compiles, basically applying `Compile` to your mapped function. Of course, `Compile` uses its own versions for compilable functions, so whatever top-level definitions you have made won't fire.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin so.. is anybody going to answer? :) or is it duplicate/simple mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is related to my own question [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121) though the circumstance is different.  As already stated in the comments:

> I can only speculate, I guess that the compiler sees Identity and
>   assumes it knows how that behaves, not looking for changed definition.
>   – ssch Oct 24 '13 at 21:37
>
> Map auto-compiles, basically applying Compile to your mapped function.
>   Of course, Compile uses its own versions for compilable functions, so
>   whatever top-level definitions you have made won't fire. – Leonid
>   Shifrin Oct 24 '13 at 21:56

Whether it be by auto-compilation or by special optimization for Packed Arrays, one must accept that top-level definitions and attributes may not be used in some cases.